# Different Ubuntu versions across cpu and gpu serving container

Tags: docker, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

Can someone help me understand why [TF serving 1.13 cpu conatiner](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/tools/docker/Dockerfile#L19) moved to Ubuntu 18.04? All other tensorflow-1.13 e.g.: [TF serving gpu](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/tools/docker/Dockerfile.gpu#L19), [tf-cpu](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d73faf5fbb7c8bfbf96cc6334111e4352f209e82/tensorflow/tools/dockerfiles/dockerfiles/cpu.Dockerfile#L22), [tf-gpu](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d73faf5fbb7c8bfbf96cc6334111e4352f209e82/tensorflow/tools/dockerfiles/dockerfiles/gpu.Dockerfile#L22) are based on 16.04.

Comment: This was intended to keep up to date with TensorFlow.  GPU images weren't moved to 18.04 yet as the CUDA 9.2 + Ubuntu 18.04 images are experimental. CUDA 10 + Ubuntu 18.04 is not experimental so there's no reason to not migrate to 18.04 for GPU images now. I think in the process of migrating to the new Dockerfile assembly system on TF, it got downgraded (unintentionally?).

You can raise a GitHub request for the same in the path, https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues, for an accurate answer

Answer (score 0):

This was intended to keep up to date with `TensorFlow`.

GPU images weren't moved to `18.04` yet as the `CUDA 9.2 + Ubuntu 18.04` images are experimental.

`CUDA 10 + Ubuntu 18.04` is not experimental so there's no reason to not migrate to `18.04` for `GPU` images now.

I think in the process of migrating to the new `Dockerfile assembly` system on `TF`, it got downgraded (unintentionally?).

You can raise a GitHub request for the same in the path,

https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues, for an accurate answer